# Filter out values less than a threshold from a CSV file

Tags: csv, awk

My CSV file is tab delimited, and I am trying to filter out the p values that are greater than `0.05` (in another way, I want to keep the entries with `p <= 0.05`). The p values are in the 7th column, and I tried to use the following:

```
 awk '$7 <= 0.05 {print $0}' rawFile.csv > filteredFile.csv
```

But this filtering does not work, it returns the file without filtering.

The p-values in the `column #7` are something like this: `0.33532935, 0.0, 0.8591287`

Comment: Your logic belongs inside the curly braces

Comment: No. That awk code is fine. Can you give us some full sample input lines?

Comment: `CSV file is tab delimited` ??!! Are you sure? CSV stands for Comma Separated Value, hence delimiter is assumed to be `,` by default. Can you show us a sample file? If my suspicion is correct you may need `awk -F,`

Comment: try to `awk '{ print $7 }' rawFile.csv | more` to make sure you indeed retrieve the right column. Then play with `-F'x'` (x being a delimiter) and see if it helps.

Comment: If the file is tab-separated, tell awk: `awk -F '\t' '$7 <= 0.05' raw`. If any of $1 to $6 contains spaces, then that throws off your field numbering since the default field separator is "whitespace".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS='\t'} {if ($7 < 0.05) print $0}'
```

The BEGIN clause gives you a place to change the default Field Separator (FS) to a tab character ('\t'). This won't work in older versions of awk (and gawk might be a helpful alternative).

The main logic happens inside the second set of curly braces ... where you'll say to print the line if column 7 is <= 0.05.

Comment: This is worse than what the OP started out with. The choice of quotes means that `\t` is interpreted by the shell, not by awk. It therefore becomes `t` (try `echo \t`) if you don't believe me :). It is also completely unnecessary to use `if` here - the structure of an awk script is `condition { action }`. The best way to set the field separator to a tab character is to use `awk -F '\t'`.